# Node.js + Connect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need some explanations.
i have app.js:

...use(rewrite)
    .use(...)

rewrite.js:

```
....
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
.....
if (match) {
    findPostIdBySlug(match[1], function(err, id) {
    .....
    next();
});
....
```

I did not get to create a function findPostIdBySlug()
I mean when i try just:

```
var findPostIdBySlug = function() {
return;}
```

nothing going on. Program just stop before next() in rewrite.js. What do I have to implement this function (findPostIdBySlug) in the code to run without hang-ups? And where should I place the function itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `next()` is within the anonymous `function`'s body:

```
findPostIdBySlug(match[1], function(err, id) {
    next();
});
```

Then, `findPostIdBySlug()` needs to at least call that `function`:

```
var findPostIdBySlug = function (slug, callback) {
    callback();
};
```

So that it can in turn call `next()`.

---

Also note that all paths in a middleware should lead to `next()` or a response. Including when there isn't a `match` and `findPostIdBySlug` won't be called.

```
if (match) {
    findPostIdBySlug(match[1], function(err, id) {
        next();
    });
} else {
    next();
}
```